# Codeigniter page needs to be refreshed before custom title is displayed?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've come across the strangest problem.

I'm creating some custom titles and implementing the facebook open graph meta tags for sharing

```
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $metadescription; ?>" />            
        <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
        <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $imageurl; ?>" />
        <?php if ($adult == '1' && !$this->auth->loggedin()) : ?>                
            <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/fotoleaf-adult-image.jpg" />
        <?php else : ?>                
            <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $metadescription; ?>" /> 

        <!-- Twitter Card data -->

        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
        <meta name="twitter:site" content="@fotoleaf">
        <meta name="twitter:title" content="<?php echo $title; ?>">
        <meta name="twitter:description" content="<?php echo $metadescription; ?>" >

        <!-- Twitter Summary card images must be at least 200x200px -->
        <?php if ($adult == '1' && !$this->auth->loggedin()) : ?>                                
            <meta name="twitter:image" content="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/fotoleaf-adult-image.jpg"> 
        <?php else : ?>                                
            <meta name="twitter:image" content="<?php echo $image; ?>"> 
        <?php endif; ?>
```

However it doesn't seem to take effect unless I refresh the page. So I get all PHP errors of undefined variables.

I'm loading it the same as all other views.

```
$this->load->view('v1/header_photo_view', $data);
$this->load->view('v1/photo_view', $photodata);
$this->load->view('v1/footer');

// SOCIAL AND SEO
        foreach ($photodata['photographer'] as $photog) {

            if ($photog['firstName'] != NULL) {
                $photogName = $photog['firstName'] . ' ' . $photog['lastName'];
            } else {
                $photogName = $photog['username']; 
            }
        }

        if ($photodata['photos']['title'] == NULL) {
                $data['title'] =  "Untitled. by ". $photogName;
        } else {
            $data['title']  =  $photodata['photos']['title']. " by ". $photogName;
        }

        $data['metadescription'] = $data['title'] . " was shared on fotoleaf. The place to share only your best photos.";

        $data['imageurl']       = site_url('photo') . "/" . $photodata['photos']['id'];
        $data['image']          = $photodata['photos']['upload_path'] . $photodata['photos']['file_name'];
        $data['adult']          = $photodata['photos']['adult'];
```

Is there someway of forcing it to refresh before it loads up?

Comment: Can i Show $data variable

Answer (score 0):

I moved the $data variable code down to just above loading the views and that seems to have fixed it.